# 403 error with ajax on CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I want to use Ajax (with the JQuery plugin Datatables) on my CodeIgniter application and when I put the address of the controller, I have a 403 error.
I use the 3.1.8 version of Codeigniter.
My code :

```
$('#Table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: {
        url: '<?= base_url('myController/data');?>',
        "type": "POST"
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "col1" },
        { "data": "col2" },
        { "data": "col3" },
    ]
} );
```

I tried to put the $config['csrf_regenerate'] at false but nothing change

Comment: It should be `'<?= base_url('myController/data');?>',`  - you're missing single quotes on your base url parameter.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it but notinh change, I have the error

Comment: try site_url() in place of base_url()

Answer (score 1):

You need a csrf token as well to be passed with your ajax data. Without it you'll get 403 error. Since, $config['csrf_regenerate'] is false in your config, you only need to get the token value once, and use it in all your  requests.

Use the below functions to get the token name and get a value for it.

```
$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
$this->security->get_csrf_hash();
```

In your controller method, you set the values of `$data['csrf_token_name']` and `$data['csrf_token_hash']` using the above methods to be used in the view code below.

```
$('#Table').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    ajax: {
        url: '<?= site_url('myController/data');?>',
        "type": "POST",
        data: { '<?php echo $csrf_token_name; ?>' : '<?php echo $csrf_token_hash; ?>' }
    },
    "columns": [
        { "data": "col1" },
        { "data": "col2" },
        { "data": "col3" },
    ]
} );
```

Comment: And there is no security problem even if the $config['csrf_regenerate'] is false ?
Have I to put "$this->security->get_csrf_token_name();
$this->security->get_csrf_hash();" in my view ?

Answer (score 0):

Your Url shoud look like :

```
url: "<?= base_url('myController/data');?>",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"url": base_url + 'myController/data',
```

try this as your url, echo in myController to see if you are going to the url or not.

I hope you've permission to access that path.